# TransitionDelegate in flutter - Navigation 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, navigation

I am new to Flutter and I have currently switched to use Navigation 2.0, and as you might know it's somehow complex at least for me. I am developing a mobile application and I really wanna customize the animations of my pages in the navigator, I tried to use MaterialPageRoute instead of MaterialPage in the pages list but it didn't work. Then I found out about the TransitionDelegate but I really couldn't do much to customize (for example a bounceOut animation for my pages). I will be thankful if someone can guide me through this.